# Python Dict Set Class Initializers

Tags: python

I am having a hard time figuring out how I should initialize my class. So, when I do it this way I do get a result but its also returning the boolean types. I only want it to return the normal numbers any ideas ? ex. odds

```
class DictSet:

    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements = {}
        for i in elements:
            self.elements[i] = True

    def addElement(self, x):
        self.elements.update(x)

    def deleteElement(self, x):
        for i in (self.elements):
            if i == x:
                del self.elements[x]

    def member(self, x):
         for i in (self.elements):
            if i == x:
                return True
            return False                    #Checks if its an item

    def intersection(self, set2):
        add = []
        for i in self.elements:
            if i in set2.elements:
                add.append(i)
        return DictSet(add)  # Returns Intersected New List

    def union(self, set2):
        return DictSet(list(self.elements.keys()) + list(set2.elements.keys()))  #Puts all the elements together

    def subtract(self, set2):
        sub = []
        for i in self.elements:
            if i not in set2.elements:
                sub.append(i)
        return DictSet(sub)       # Only return ones set of elements

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Set: " + str(self.elements) + ">"


def main():
    all = DictSet([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    odds = DictSet([1,3,5,7,9])
    evens = DictSet([2,4,6,8,10])
    print("all", odds.union(evens))
    print("all", evens.union(odds))
    print("empty", odds.intersection(evens))
    print("odds", all.intersection(odds))
    print("odds", all.subtract(evens))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Couldnt format this properly so there's gonna be some formatting issues

Comment: What does "return the normal numbers" mean? Return what numbers, from what function? You've not described what the semantics of this class are supposed to be, so I can't tell if what I see in the code is buggy or working as intended.

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry my ex. got cut off so my first print should be all <Set: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]> instead Im getting 
all <Set: {1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: ''}> I changed true to "" within the last couple mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to accomplish, but I can tell you why you get the output you get.

First, I'd like to note that it's the `__repr__` function that determines how your object is displayed when `print` is invoked on your object. In your `__repr__` method, you have the statement `return "<Set: " + str(self.elements) + ">"`. Your field,  `self.elements`. is a dictionary. If you use the `str()` function on a dictionary, it turns the dictionary into a string starting with `{` and ending with `}`, such that each key/value pair is listed. Your keys are the integers 1 through 10, and you've set all the values to `True` (as per your `__init__`). So, for the code you've given us, you'll see output:

`('all', <Set: {1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: True}>)`

because `self.elements` str() method produces output `{1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: True}`. If you want to just display `('all', <Set: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]>)`, then you'll need to change your `__repr__` to only display the **keys** of `self.elements` (not the **keys** and **values**). You could do it like so:

`__repr__(self):
    return "<Set: " + str([key for key in self.elements]) + ">"`

`[key for key in self.elements]` creates a list of keys from your `self.elements` dictionary field, per [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Or, since you already have something like this in your other code, you could just do:

`__repr__(self):
    return "<Set: " + str(self.elements.keys()) + ">"`

I think this last definition of `__repr__` is a little clearer, the first one was just what immediately popped into my head.

I'd also like to note that if the output I've described is your end goal, then you don't need a dictionary type for `self.elements`. It would be clearer/better to just use a list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use the values of your dictionary, but only the keys, it's more fitting to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a `dict`:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.